# Can I use NAT64 to route public IPV6 traffic to internal IPV4?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, nat, ipv6

I have a bunch of public IPv6 addresses and some services that run IPv4 only. [Can I use NAT64](http://www.litech.org/tayga/) to connect these services?

Is there another solution like a proxy or something?

Comment: This is NAT46, not NAT64. And, unless those devices are truly ancient, you ought to be able to just give them IPv6.

Comment: Its not devices, that need the IPV4 support its more like multiplayer game servers that don't have support for IPV6 yes its possible they might be old. So you're saying NAT46 will help?

Comment: If the game _servers_ don't support IPv6, the game _clients_ probably won't either. As far as your network goes, you should dual stack everything, and then deal with any applications that may need help.

Comment: @kevzettler I have been working on a product for this kind of situation. Are you interested in evaluating how well it fits your use case?

Comment: @kasperd what kind of product? a solution to the networking issue? or the full hosting idea?

Comment: @kevzettler A piece of software that does the translation between IPv6 and IPv4. One instance of this software can connect a fairly large IPv4 LAN to the IPv6 backbone. Handles both servers and clients.

Comment: @kasperd I'd be interested in checking it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a possible way to do that. I would recommend against it though. The IPv6 header is bigger than the IPv4 header, so the conversion will make the packet bigger. The IPv6 packets get fragmented and performance drops. Even if fragmentation is prevented (TCP MSS, lowering the IPv4 MTU) the NAT64 implementation might create atomic fragments.

Unfortunately some devices have problems processing fragments or block them. You could say that this is their problem, not your problem, you still might want to take that into account.

If you have the choice I would use a dual-stack proxy instead of NAT.

Comment: Any suggestions for the dual-stack setup?

Comment: Take a look at http://www.internetsociety.org/deploy360/resources/making-content-available-over-ipv6/. It is a tutorial that I wrote about this for ISOC Deploy360.